# How to get AssetBundleManifest from AssetBundle in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have read [AssetBundles Document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Native.html) and also tried to get the manifest from the specific `assetbundle` like the document. I want to get character's manifest but the manifest from the code returns null.

I've changed the `AssetBundleManifest` at line 5 to `character` or `character.manifest` and it is also null:

```
private IEnumerator LoadAssetBundleManifest()
{
    string assetBundlePath = Application.dataPath + "/../AssetBundles/Android/character";
    AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(assetBundlePath); // assetBundle also have data.
    var manifest = assetBundle.LoadAsset<AssetBundleManifest>("AssetBundleManifest");

    print(manifest); // manifest = null

    yield return null;
}
```

This image is the folder of my asset:

[image: my assetbundle environment]

PS. Now, I'm using `Unity 2018.1.1f1`.

Comment: Can you explain why you need AssetBundleManifest?

Comment: I just want to get the CRC number from the manifest to check if the assetbundle from server is the same number as the local assetbundle

Comment: With `AssetBundleManifest.GetAssetBundleHash`?

Comment: Yes, and also to get the Dependencies info from the manifest to resolve a problem like when the bundle's sharing the dependencies with another bundle.

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Comment: at the end. I just load the manifest and read with YAML format.

The asset bundle of my project doesn't have any dependencies which mean 1 asset bundle for something that should not link to another asset bundle.

so that's it. I load manifest for checking that the current version of manifest that I have is the newest version or not. if it does not then load the new manifest and also asset bundle.

Answer (score 3):

You were close to solving it. The file you had to load in `AssetBundle.LoadFromFile` was the file `Android`, so your code would be like this:

```cs
private IEnumerator LoadAssetBundleManifest()
{
    string assetBundlePath = Application.dataPath + "/../AssetBundles/Android/Android";
    AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(assetBundlePath); // assetBundle also have data.
    var manifest = assetBundle.LoadAsset<AssetBundleManifest>("AssetBundleManifest");
    
    Hash128 characterHash = manifest.GetAssetBundleHash("character");
    Debug.Log(characterHash.ToString()); //hash of the character AssetBundle
    
    yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
void LoadAsserBundle()
{
    AssetBundle manifestAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(GetAssetBundlePath("StreamingAssets"));
    AssetBundleManifest assetBundleManifest = manifestAssetBundle.LoadAsset<AssetBundleManifest>("assetbundlemanifest");

    AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(GetAssetBundlePath("character"));
    Hash128 hash = assetBundleManifest.GetAssetBundleHash(assetBundle.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read the following [manual page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Native.html) at the **Loading AssetBundle Manifests**

> Loading AssetBundle Manifests
> Loading AssetBundle manifests can be incredibly useful. Especially when dealing with AssetBundle dependencies.

To get a useable AssetBundleManifest object, you’ll need to load that additional AssetBundle (the one that’s named the same thing as the folder it’s in) and load an object of type AssetBundleManifest from it.

Loading the manifest itself is done exactly the same as any other Asset from an AssetBundle:
`AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(manifestFilePath); AssetBundleManifest manifest = assetBundle.LoadAsset<AssetBundleManifest>("AssetBundleManifest");`

Now you have access to the AssetBundleManifest API calls through the manifest object from the above example. From here you can use the manifest to get information about the AssetBundles you built. This information includes dependency data, hash data, and variant data for the AssetBundles.

accordingly and from what you show above you are passing the wrong manifest file,
you should pass Android asstbundle instead of what you pass.

Comment: It would be nice to move a section of the man pages into the answer here so if the link ever breaks the person can still get the gist and see code to help them out.